# is there a way to use my app to authenticate users with only a StackOverflow account with the stackExchange oauth api 2.1?

Tags: support

Recently I registered an app in https://stackapps.com/ to provide a way to authenticate users with their stackoverflow account. but I notice that https://stackexchange.com/oauth only works for users with a stackexchange account.

I didn't find a way to set the authentication for only users with a stackoverflow account in the documentation site https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: The situation is indeed quite strange. A user could create a bare StackExchange.com account for use as an OpenID, but that account isn't necessarily connected to other sites in the SE network, and it basically has no useful information that you can use with the StackExchange API. From my understanding, you can't even pull a display name or a profile link from such an account because these are only available in the "sub-accounts" of the other SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Stack Overflow account (or an account on *any* Stack Exchange site) automatically creates a Stack Exchange account as well.

Comment: I created a new user on stackoverflow and with this user connected. When I try to connect this user, stackexchange ask me for a login.

Comment: @agares Just use the same login you used for the other sites. You already have a Stack Exchange network account: http://stackexchange.com/users/1073949/agares